# How to extract content within square brackets in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to extract the content inside the square brackets. 
So far I have been using this, which works but I was wondering instead of using this delete function, if I could directly use something in regex.

```
a = "This is such a great day [cool awesome]" 
a[/\[.*?\]/].delete('[]') #=> "cool awesome"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost.

```
a = "This is such a great day [cool awesome]"
a[/\[(.*?)\]/, 1]
# => "cool awesome"
a[/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/]
# => "cool awesome"
```

The first one relies on extracting a group instead of a full match; the second one leverages lookahead and lookbehind to avoid the delimiters in the final match.

Comment: what if there are multiple occurrence and I want all of them in an array?

Comment: @AsnadAtta: Use [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-scan).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Regular expression using [`Regexp#=~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E).

```
/\[(?<inside_brackets>.+)\]/ =~ a 
  => 25

inside_brackets
  => "cool awesome"
```

This way you assign `inside_brackets` to the string which matches the regular expression if any, which I think it is more readable.

**Note:** Be careful to place the regular expression at the left hand side.

Comment: Why does it return 25?

Comment: It appears to be the position of the match in the string: `"This is such a great day [cool awesome]"[25..-1] #=> "[cool awesome]"`...This matches the [`String#=~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) method, but no mention of it's behavior in the Regex version of the method docs; even though they do different things (slightly: ie, `string =~ regex` is not quite the same as `regex =~ string`), this one details appears the same